# build.sbt: how to add spark dependencies

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-streaming

Hello I am trying to download `spark-core`, `spark-streaming`, `twitter4j`, and `spark-streaming-twitter` in the build.sbt file below:

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.4.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "3.0.3",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "3.0.3"
)

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.10" % "0.9.0-incubating"
```

I simply took this `libraryDependencies` online so I am not sure which versions, etc. to use.

Can someone please explain to me how I should fix this .sbt files. I spent a couple hours trying to figure it out but none of the suggesstion worked. I installed `scala` through homebrew and I am on version `2.11.8`

All of my errors were about:

```
Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes.
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing Scala 2.11 and 2.10 artifacts. You have:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

And then:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.4.1"
```

Where the `2.10` artifact is being required. You are also mixing Spark versions instead of using a consistent version:

```
// spark 1.6.1
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"

// spark 1.4.1
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.4.1"

// spark 0.9.0-incubating
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.10" % "0.9.0-incubating"
```

Here is a `build.sbt` that fixes both problems:

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "1.6.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % sparkVersion
)
```

You also don't need to manually add `twitter4j` dependencies since they are added transitively by `spark-streaming-twitter`.

Comment: Thank you so much! One quick question will the version of scala (`2.11.8`) work with all of the spark libraries which have the version `1.6.1`?

Comment: Yes. Spark 1.6.1 has builds for both 2.10 and 2.11 versions of scala.

Comment: I have one more question regarding this. Sorry about that! When I do `sbt run` it seems like the third dependency `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion` is not being downloaded and therefore in my scala file in `src/main/scala/example.scala` I am getting an error when initializing my spark context: `16/06/21 21:18:14 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.UnknownHostException: LM-SFA-11002982: LM-SFA-11002982: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: This error is not related to the dependencies being downloaded or not. You should open another question to solve this doubt.

Comment: perfect !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 8):

It works for me:

```
name := "spark_local"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "3.0.5",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "3.0.5",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.0.0"
)
```