# ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext. java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: DEFAULT_TINY_CACHE_SIZE

Tags: java, apache-spark, netty

I am trying to run a spark job but getting below error.

```
21/12/24 15:40:43 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: DEFAULT_TINY_CACHE_SIZE
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyUtils.getPrivateStaticField(NettyUtils.java:131)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyUtils.createPooledByteBufAllocator(NettyUtils.java:118)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportServer.init(TransportServer.java:95)
```

Here is the netty dependencies which are being used:

```
netty-3.7.0.Final.jar netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar
netty-buffer-4.1.69.Final.jar netty-codec-4.1.69.Final.jar
netty-codec-http-4.1.69.Final.jar netty-codec-socks-4.1.60.Final.jar
netty-common-4.1.69.Final.jar netty-handler-4.1.69.Final.jar
netty-handler-proxy-4.1.60.Final.jar netty-resolver-4.1.69.Final.jar
netty-transport-4.1.69.Final.jar
netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.69.Final.jar
netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.60.Final-linux-x86_64.jar
netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.69.Final.jar
netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.60.Final-osx-x86_64.jar
netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.69.Final.jar
```

I have tried with netty-all version 4.0.43 also but somehow i get same error.
spark version used: 2.2.3
Can anyone please help me why this issue is coming.

Comment: Check this out --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/37958371/5911696

Comment: i tried adding scala 2.11 for spark streaming twitter dependency but same error i get.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you force the same netty version for everything. You have multiple versions on the Classpath. Just use 4.1.72.Final